# Transistor switch logic, multiple lines

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, switches, npn, pnp

I have the following problem that I need your help solving.

I have two digital input signals, let's call them D1 and D2, they are 0-5V, and max available current is 20 mA, and two output signals, let's call them O1, and O2.

So D1 and D2, must never be on at the same time, and will be controlled from a micro controler, one way would be to make sure in the code they don't switch on, but maybe it will be better if I can add a safeguard to prevent accidental switching.

[image: Circuit]

If D1 is on (5V), then

`O1:  12V@0.5A
O2: 0.3V@-0.5A`

If D2 is on (5V), then

`O1: 0.3V@-0.5A
O2:  12V@0.5A`

If D1 and D2 are off (0V), then

`O1: 0V
O2: OV`

The transistor at the bottom is probably an overkill, as it can support up to 74A.

So using the circuit bellow I can accomplish switch the output to be 12V, at 0.5A, or up to 74A, now how can I use another transistor/(s), IC, or another solution to accomplish the safeguard.

The circuit bellow can be used to switch the line as needed, using the micro controller, I've tried this circuit and it works correctly for switching the one output, but how can I make them work together.
[image: High side transistor switch]

The circuit bellow can be used to lower the voltage to the necessary voltage required.
[image: Voltage divider]

Comment: You show the not-active output being 0.3V @ negative 0.5A.  What exactly do you mean?

Comment: In the bottom figure, your 0.3v is derived from a voltage divider, and the voltage on the meter represents no load.  The circuit won't work under any load, much less 0.5A.  With the 3.9K resistor it can't even draw more than 3 mA.  You can't use a voltage divider to supply a variable amount of current because the voltage will change.

Comment: @tcrosley, Actually there is load, but I forgot to add it to the picture.  Yeah actually you are right, it can't flow more than 3 mA through the voltage divider. I didn't really think about the current, now that you say, yeah you are right. So it will have to be done in a different way.

Comment: @DwayneReid, so the situation is like this I have a box controller, and it has some wires that come out of it, I'm trying to recreate this, so I can control it with an micro controller. A total of 9 wires come out of it, I've recreated them, except for these 2, I can't seem to make it work. The box is sealed so I can't open it, I tried playing with it with dedicated power source to confirm that it will work, and it works, as long as you supply the correct voltages to these 2 outputs.

Comment: @ilijamt I think what DwayneReid wanted to ask you is, when the output is set to 0.3V@-0.5A, does this mean it will SINK 0.5A? Or is it a typo?

Comment: It's not a typo, so yeah it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a 600 ma / 1 a   ic.
Dual H-Bridge Motor Driver for DC or Steppers - 600ma - L293D

$2.50 from adafruit  even cheaper from china [ $.50 ]

see data sheet at  http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/l293d.pdf

L293   1 amp  requires external clamp diodes.
L293d  600 ma  has internal clamp diodes.

I use one of these, to run 2 12v dc motors,  n gage model trains. 
pulse 1 side of bridge for fwd, and other for reverse.
both hi will cause both outputs hi,  no problem, 
  no voltage differential therefore no current.
i use arduino pwm to controll speed.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I don't see a question.

Comment: Yeah this worked.